# Simple connect four game in c

Tags: c, arrays

In this game, you have a 9 column, 6 row board. At the beginning, the first and last columns are populated with alternating player tokens. The computer will randomly pick which player (the human or the computer) moves first. That player drops their token into one of the middle 7 columns of the board. (The leftmost and rightmost columns are already full). The next player then does the same thing. At any point, if a player drops a token which completes a set of 5 tokens in a row (horizontally, vertically, or diagonally), that player wins the game.

I cannot use library functions other than `printf()`, `scanf()`, `putc()` and `getc()`.
I have some trouble with the diagonalCheck, please help me 
this is my current code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BOARD_ROWS 6
#define BOARD_COLS 9

void printBoard(char *board);
int takeTurn(char *board, int player, const char*);
int checkWin(char *board);
int checkfour(char* board , int,int,int,int);
int horizontalCheck(char *board);
int verticalCheck(char *board);
int diagonalCheck (char *board);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    const char *PIECES = "XO";
    char board[BOARD_ROWS*BOARD_COLS];
    for(int i =0; i< BOARD_ROWS*BOARD_COLS ; i ++){
         board[i] = '.';
    }
    int turn, done=0;

    for (turn=0; turn < BOARD_ROWS*BOARD_COLS && !done; turn++){
        printBoard(board);
        while(!takeTurn(board,turn %2, PIECES))
        {
            printBoard(board);
            puts("**Column full!**\n");
        }
    done = checkWin(board);
    }
    printBoard(board);
    if (turn == BOARD_ROWS*BOARD_COLS && !done)
    {
        puts("It's a tie!");
    }

    else{
        turn--;
        printf("player %d (%c) wins!\n", turn %2 + 1, PIECES[turn%2]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void printBoard(char *board){
    int row,col;
    puts("\n *****Connect tour*****\n");
    for(row=0; row < BOARD_ROWS; row++){
        for(col =0; col <BOARD_COLS;col++){
            printf(" %c",board[BOARD_COLS * row+col]);
        }
        puts(" ");
        //puts(".......");
    }
puts(" ");
puts(" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 \n");
}

int takeTurn(char*board, int player, const char *PIECES)
{
    int row,col = 0;
    printf("Player %d (%c): \nEnter number Coordinate:", player+1, PIECES[player]);
    while(1){
        if (1 != scanf("%d", &col) || col < 1 || col >9){
            while(getchar() != '\n');
            puts("number out of bounds! Try again.");
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    col--;
    for(row = BOARD_ROWS-1; row>= 0; row--){
        printf("here");
         if(board[BOARD_COLS * row+col] == '.'){
            board[BOARD_COLS * row+col] = PIECES[player];
            return 1;
         }
    }
    return 0;
    }
int checkWin(char *board){
    return(horizontalCheck(board)|| verticalCheck(board) || diagonalCheck(board));
}

int checkfour(char *board, int a, int b, int c , int d){
    if (board[a] == board[b] && board[b]==board[c] && board[c]==board[d]&&board[a] != '.'){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int horizontalCheck(char *board){
    int row,col,idx;
    const int WIDTH = 1;
    for (row=0; row<BOARD_ROWS; row++){
        for(col = 0; col < BOARD_COLS-3; col++){
            idx = BOARD_COLS * row+col; 
            if(checkfour(board, idx, idx + WIDTH, idx + WIDTH *2, idx + WIDTH*3)){
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int verticalCheck(char*board){
    int row,col,idx;
    const int HEIGHT = 7;
    for(row = 0; row< BOARD_ROWS-3; row++){
        for(col = 0; col < BOARD_COLS;col++){
            idx = BOARD_COLS*row+col;
            if (checkfour(board, idx,idx+HEIGHT, idx+ HEIGHT*2, idx+ HEIGHT*3)){
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int diagonalCheck(char *board){
    int row,col,idx,Count = 0;
    const int DIAG_RGT = 6, DIAG_LFT = 8;
    for (row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS-3; row++){
        for(col = 0; col<BOARD_COLS;col++){
            idx = BOARD_COLS*row+col;
            if ((Count <=3 && checkfour(board, idx, idx+DIAG_LFT , idx+DIAG_LFT*2, idx + DIAG_LFT*3))||(
            Count >=3&&checkfour(board,idx,idx+DIAG_RGT,idx+DIAG_RGT*2, idx+DIAG_RGT*3))){
                return 1;
            }
            Count++;
            }
            Count = 0;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question? What specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Your inner `for` `for(col = 0; col<BOARD_COLS;col++){` goes until `BOARD_COLS` instead of `BOARD_COLS-3`. In the inner `if`s you will need to check whether there is such a diagonal into one direction (`DIAG_RGT`) or the other (`DIAG_LFT`). It would make sense that in the first `if` you would use `DIAG_RGT` to compute the indexes and in the other `if` you would use `DIAG_LFT`.

Comment: so I need to separate  DIAG_RGT and DIAG_LFT ?

Comment: @buncher I'm not sure what you mean by separating these two variables. My point is that you need to check whether index, index + DIAG_RGT, index + 2 * DIAG_RGT, index + 3 * DIAG_RGT matches your checkfour and you will also need to check whether index, index + DIAG_LFT, index + 2 * DIAG_LFT, index + 3 * DIAG_LFT matches your checkfour. You want to check two diagonals whether they match your criteria for each point (except edge points).

Comment: yeah I made a mistake in that, I already fix it and it works well for right, but DIAG_LFT still have some problem

Comment: @buncher can you tell me how the problem that you experience manifests?

Comment: It works in this side / but it does not work on this side \

Comment: @buncher that's clear from your previous comment, I would like to get an example of your board state where it doesn't work and the point where it fails.

Comment: @buncher please give examples of problems.

Comment: @buncher let's take the first problem you have mentioned as our example. Can you print out Count, idx, board[idx + DIAG_LFT], board[idx + DIAG_LFT * 2], board[idx + DIAG_LFT * 3], board[idx + DIAG_RGT], board[idx + DIAG_RGT * 2] and board[idx + DIAG_RGT * 3]?

Comment: Also, conditions with Count do not look right. I think you need Count to ensure that there are actually points to check with your columns. Count <= 3 for the direction of right is incorrect, just imagine four x values starting from the top-left corner. You need Count < BOARD_COLS - 3  for the right-hand direction (DIAG_LFT) and you need Count >= 3 for the right-hand direction (which is correct in your code).

Comment: So change Count <= 3 to Count < BOARD_COLS - 3